# Blue and Purple Default links, how to remove?

Tags: html, css

This is one of the links in my nav:

```
<li><a href="#live-now" class="navBtn"><span id="navLiveNow" class="white innerShadow textShadow">Live Now</span></a></li>
```

I also have the following in my css:

```
a { text-decoration: none; }
a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
a:focus { text-decoration: none; }
a:hover, a:active { text-decoration: none; }
```

But the links still display in the awful blue/purple visited /hover html default. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to override the color:

```
a { color:red } /* Globally */

/* Each state */

a:visited { text-decoration: none; color:red; }
a:hover { text-decoration: none; color:blue; }
a:focus { text-decoration: none; color:yellow; }
a:hover, a:active { text-decoration: none; color:black }
```

Answer (score 3):

**REMOVE DEFAULT LINK SOLVED**
that :visited thing is css.... you just go to your HTML and add a simple

> < a href="" **style="text-decoration: none"** > < /a>

... thats the way html pages used to be

Comment: The question is about the **colour** which your code doesn't touch.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="https://www." style="color: inherit;"target="_blank">
```

For CSS inline style, this worked best for me.

Comment: This does not work if you don't overwrite color in parent element.

Answer (score 1):

Hey define color `#000` into as like you and modify your css as like this

```
.navBtn { text-decoration: none; color:#000; }
.navBtn:visited { text-decoration: none; color:#000; }
.navBtn:hover { text-decoration: none; color:#000; }
.navBtn:focus { text-decoration: none; color:#000; }
.navBtn:hover, .navBtn:active { text-decoration: none; color:#000; }
```

or this

```
 li a { text-decoration: none; color:#000; }
 li a:visited { text-decoration: none; color:#000; }
 li a:hover { text-decoration: none; color:#000; }
 li a:focus { text-decoration: none; color:#000; }
 li a:hover, .navBtn:active { text-decoration: none; color:#000; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wants display anchors in your own choice of colors than you should define the color in anchor tag property in **CSS** like this:-

```
a { text-decoration: none; color:red; }
a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
a:focus { text-decoration: none; }
a:hover, a:active { text-decoration: none; }
```

see the demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/zSWbD/7/

Answer (score 0):

By default link color is **blue** and the **visited** color is **purple**. Also, the text-decoration is **underlined** and the color is **blue**.
If you want to keep the same color for visited, hover and focus then follow below code-

For example color is: **#000**

```
a:visited, a:hover, a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
```

If you want to use a different color for hover, visited and focus. For example **Hover** color: red **visited** color: green and **focus** color: yellow  then follow below code

```
   a:hover {
        color: red;
    }
    a:visited {
        color: green;
    }
    a:focus {
        color: yellow;
    }
```

NB: good practice is to use color code.

Answer (score -1):

When you set the style of a tag in your `CSS` it goes global (as Andreas Wong mentioned), IE, it is applied in every scenario to that tag (visited, hovered, focus etc...), unless you manually change it

So you can do it like bellow:

```
a{
    color : blue;
}
```

Now you can specify the color in a certain scenario:

```
a{
    color : blue;
}
a: focus{
    color : skyblue;
{
```

Comment: Your examples are literally overriding the default colours.

Comment: `a: focus` is a syntax error.

Comment: There's nothing (at least nothing that is correct) in your answer that wasn't already covered by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10312896/19068) from a decade ago.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to override all the behaviors of text links that use the `a` tag, apply the following style below:

```
a { 
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: inherit;
}
```