How can I make sure that when I press the box/image on it, I'm redirected to another page?
rn I´m building an online shop for my school. And i have Images or Boxes with pictures of the products. Now I want that people can press the image and get instantly redirected to another page with some infos about the product. How can I do it?
And I´m sorry for my bad english, thats because I´m German :(
   ``` <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>  
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>fashion</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_2_Seite.css" media="all" />
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <a href= "1-Seite.html" class= logo>fashion</a>
            <nav class="navbar">
                <a href="1-Seite.html">Home</a>
                <a href="2-Seite.html">Shop</a>
                <a href="#">Über uns</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        
    
    <section class="products" id="products">
        <h1 class="heading"> latest <span> products</span> </h1>
        <div class="box-container">
            
            <div class="box">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="Products/bb.hoodie.png" width="50%;" id="box" alt="">
                    <div class="icons">
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "cart-btn">add to cart</a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>MEDIUM FIT B HOODIE</h3>
                    <div class="price"> 1.225€ <span></span> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        
            <div class="box">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="Products/bbjacke.png" width="50%;" id="box" alt="">
                    <div class="icons">
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "cart-btn">add to cart</a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>RACING JACKET</h3>
                    <div class="price"> 3.100€ <span></span> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        
            <div class="box">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="Products/nfs.hose.png" width="50%;" alt="">
                    <div class="icons">
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "cart-btn">add to cart</a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>HEAVY WASHED BOMBER</h3>
                    <div class="price">2.175€ <span></span> </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        
            <div class="box">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="Products/nfs.bomber.png" width="50%;" alt="">
                    <div class="icons">
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "cart-btn">add to cart</a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>GREY INSIDE OUT BOMBER</h3>
                    <div class="price"> 2.750€ <span></span> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        
        <div class="box">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="Products/ro.coat.png" width="50%;" alt="">
                    <div class="icons">
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "cart-btn">add to cart</a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>HOODED COAT GREY/BLACK </h3>
                    <div class="price"> 4.250€ <span> </span> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        
        <div class="box">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="Products/ro.coat 2.png" width="50%;" alt="">
                    <div class="icons">
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "cart-btn">add to cart</a>
                        <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>HOODED COAT BLACK</h3>
                    <div class="price"> 4.250€ <span> </span> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        
        
        
        
    </div>
                
                        
        

    </body>
    </html>```



    body {
   
.header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding:19px 20px;
    background: #DCdCdC

}

    
.logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: -10px;
    font-size: 32px;
    padding:20px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 650;
    
}

.navbar a {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff; 
    font-weight: 600; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    margin-left: 400px;
    word-spacing: 2px;


}


.products .box-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 1.5rem;
}

.products .box-container .box{
    flex:1 1 30rem;
    box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1.5rem rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    border-radius: .5rem;
    border: .1rem solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    position: relative;
    transition: 1s; 

}


.products .box-container .box .image{
    position:relative;
    text-align: center; 
    padding-top: 2rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box:hover{
    transform:scale(1.05);

}

.products .box-container .box .image .icons {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; left:0; right: 0;
    display: flex;
}


.products .box-container .box .image .icons a {
    margin-left: 8rem;
    margin-bottom: -3rem;
    height: 4rem;
    line-height:6rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    width: 50%
    background: black);
    color:#000;
}

.products .box-container .box .content {
    padding:2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.products .box-container .box .content h3 {
    font-size:2rem;
    color: #000;
}

.products .box-container .box .content price {
    font-size:1.5rem;
    color: black;
    font-weight:bolder;
    padding-top:1rem;
    
} 


What you're describing sounds like a link (an <a> element).  Did you try creating one?  What specifically have you tried and what isn't working as expected?

@David tbh I dont even know how to create it. I dodnt relly try it. Could you explain it please?

The documentation provides examples, and any introductory HTML tutorial would be a good place to start.  You are encouraged to give that a try.

Wrap the code that you want to go to another page in an anchor link with the href set to the page you want to go to.
<a class="box" href="http://example.com">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="Products/ro.coat.png" width="50%;" alt="">
            <div class="icons">
                <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
                <a href= "#" class= "cart-btn">add to cart</a>
                <a href= "#" class= "fas fa-heart"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h3>HOODED COAT GREY/BLACK </h3>
            <div class="price"> 4.250€ <span> </span> </div>
        </div>
</a>

This will make the entire div clickable and open another page
a{
    //removes the underline for all links
    text-decoration: none;
}


Ty, it is working. But now I got the problem that the boxes arent next to each other but among each other. And under every Text in the box is a purple line

And sorry if I'm annoying, but could you maybe also take a look at my question with the video and the navar :)

Here's a link to remove the purple underline. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10312896/3071828. For the boxes not being in the right order try removing the  div and moving class="box" to the anchor . The anchor acts as a container.  If this works I'll change my reply.

It worked with the a class=box! ty, but I dont understand it with the purple lines :(

I updated my answer and included the css for removing the link underline.
